# tool with rest api to scan base64 encoded files

Tags: antivirus, rest, antimalware

I'm searching for a tool (antimalware / antivirus) that exposes a REST API and accept me to pass a base64 encoded file in order to check if it's a malicious one or not. I've tried the ClaimAV but it does not detect that a bat file (with 'format c: /s' content) as malicious file.

I've found a few websites that offers what I've being searching for, but their price is super high.

Question 1: the tool that I've being searching for is a antimalware or antivirus?

Question 2: is there any one out there that is open source?

Comment: Is `'format c: /s'` malicious?

Comment: There are online tools that allow you to upload a *hash* of the file to check if it has already been seen. VirusTotal does not meet your needs?

Comment: Why is passing base64 a requirement? Does it have to be base64?

Comment: Your second question about asking if there is such a tool is off-topic here as any list or existence of any one tool may be obsolete tomorrow.

Comment: why can't you just unencode it before scanning?

Comment: The front end passese the file as base64. I could save it on a temp folder in order to scan, but I know there's a way to pass it as base64.

Comment: @schroeder virustotal is a good one, but I'll scan thousands of files and their price will be super high.